# Wrong degree of freedom for between-subject factor in lmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I'm testing how visual perspective(1, completely first person -> 11, completely third person) can vary as a function of Culture (AA, EA), Valence (Positive, Negative) and Event Type (Memory, Imagination) while control age (continuous), sex (M, F) and SES (continuous) and allowing individual differences.

This is an unbalanced design as participants can have as we give participants 10 prompts, but participants can choose to either recall or imagine a relevant event. Therefore, each participants may have as many memories (no greater than 10) and as many imaginations (no greater than 10) as they want. In total we have 363 participants.

My dataset looks like this:

[image: Dataset]

The model I fit looks like

```
VP.full.lm <- lmer(Visual.Perspective ~ Culture * Event.Type * Valence + 
                   Sex + Age + SES +
                   (1|Participant.Number),
                 data=VP_Long)
```

When I run `anova()` function to see the effects of all variables, here is the output:

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                            Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF  F value    Pr(>F)    
Culture                      30.73   30.73     1  859.1   4.9732 0.0260008 *  
Valence                       6.38    6.38     1 3360.3   1.0322 0.3097185    
Event.Type                 1088.61 1088.61     1 3385.9 176.1759 < 2.2e-16 ***
Sex                          45.12   45.12     1  358.1   7.3014 0.0072181 ** 
Age                           7.95    7.95     1  358.1   1.2869 0.2573719    
SES                           6.06    6.06     1  358.7   0.9807 0.3226824    
Culture:Valence               6.39    6.39     1 3364.6   1.0348 0.3091004    
Culture:Event.Type           71.53   71.53     1 3389.7  11.5766 0.0006756 ***
Valence:Event.Type            2.89    2.89     1 3385.4   0.4682 0.4938573    
Culture:Valence:Event.Type    3.47    3.47     1 3390.6   0.5617 0.4536399    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

As you can see, the DF for effect of culture is off -- since culture is a between-subject factor, its DF cannot be larger than our sample size. I've tried to use `ddf = Roger-Kenward` and tested the effect of culture using `emmeans::test(contrast(emmeans(VP.full.lm,c("Culture")), "trt.vs.ctrl"), joint = T)`, yet none of these methods solved the problems with the degree of freedom issue.

I also thought about that maybe those participants who did not provide both memories and imaginations are confusing the lmer model, so I subsetted my data to only include participants who provided both types of events. However, the degree of freedom problem persists. It's also worth mentioning that once I removed the interaction between Culture and Event.Type, the degree of freedom became plausible.

I wonder if anyone knows what is going on here, and how can we fix this issue? Or is there way we can explain away this weird issue...?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I really doubt that there is anything wrong with the d.f. Remember d.f. measures the amount of information that went into a variance estimate, which isn't exactly the same as the number of subjects or groups. Remember also that the d.f. for the estimated marginal means themselves could be quite different from the d.f. for comparisons/contrasts thereof, and it is the latter d.f. that you see in this anova table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...

Not a complete solution, but some ideas:

- from a practical point of view, the difference between 363 (or even 350) denominator df and 859 ddf is very small: the manual p-value calculation based on an F-statistic of 4.9732 gives `pf(4.9732,1,350,lower.tail=FALSE)`=0.0264, hardly different from your value of 0.260.
- since you are fitting a simple model (LMM not GLMM, only a single simple random effect, etc.), you might be able to refit your model in `lme` (from the `nlme` package): it uses a simpler df computation that might give you the 'right' answer in this case. Alternatively, you can get code from [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/R/calcDenDF.R) that implements a (slightly extended) version of the algorithm from `lme`.
- since you're doing type-III Anova, you should be very careful with the parameterization/contrasts in your model: if you're not using centered (sum-to-zero) contrasts, your results may not mean what you think (the `afex::mixed()` function does some checks to make sure that this is true). It's conceivable (although I doubt it) that the contrasts are throwing of your ddf calculations as well.
- it's not clear how you're measuring "visual perspective", but if it's a ratings scale you might be better off with an ordinal response model ...

Comment: I tried running my model with lme, and it seems to work just fine. Still don't know what's going on with lmer, but at least the problem is solved for now. Thanks!

Comment: it's not really an "lmer" problem; it's a Satterthwaite/Kenward-Roger problem.